# Where to write my Jupyter-notebook file name in .rst file in Nbsphinx

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx

I have gone through the documentation and have edited the conf.py file already and than I am not getting where to write my file name in the toctree for the index.rst file ??

Jupyter notebook name : Start.ipynb

https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.5.1/usage.html#Running-Sphinx

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your notebook `Start.ipynb` as main page,
you should rename it to `index.ipynb` (and delete `index.rst`).

If you want to keep `index.rst` as main page,
you can add your `Start.ipynb` like this:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   Start
```

You can of course change (or remove) the `:maxdepth:` and `:caption:` options.